# Reading from template and updating the parameters

Tags: html, ruby, templates

i am trying to use a email template and use it in the program. i want to replace the values in the template using the program variables and .

i am having the working example of it if i include  this with in the program in the heredoc. but i want to keep this as template outside the program so that i can distribute it to others so they can customise it. which means i am trying to replace #{tabcmd} and #{img} from the template using variables from program.

but i get this error. i teied escaping it with \ but did not worl.
01:19:35PM: Exception Caught: Exiting
 Error message: (eval):5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end

i even tried body1 = `eval("\"#{body}\"")` . but it did not work. do i need to use yaml or some thing else?

**Working**

```
def sendmessage(report_name, rep_desc, to_list,  rcptList, subject_line,  body, error_file_name, table_name_n, file_name_n , log_file)

    ##########################
    # loop arround each image file and add it to the email.
    ##########################
    imtg=""
    #define global variable to loop arround each image file.
    $party=""
    file_name_n.each { |a| puts a
    fname1 = "#{Base64.encode64(File.open(a, 'rb').read)}"

    part4=<<EOF
    Content-Type: image/png; name="#{a}"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="#{a}"

    #{fname1}
    --#{marker}
    EOF

    $party << part4

    imtg <<"<IMG SRC=\"#{a}\"  alt=\"#{a}\">"
    puts imtg
    }

          tabnam = File.open(table_name_n, 'rb').read
    puts tabnam
    ##########################
    # Build email body
    ##########################
    body = <<EOF
            <html>
    <head>
    <title>Dashboards</title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',verdana;">
    <table width="100%" style="height: 100%;" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
    <!-- ============ HEADER SECTION ============== -->
    <td colspan="3" style="height: 100px;" bgcolor="#38424F" align="center"><h1><font size="3" color="white">#{report_name}</font></h1></td>
    </tr>
    #{tabcmd}
    ..
    #{img}
    ...

    EOF
```

**Not Working**

```
    ##########################
    # loop arround each image file and add it to the email.
    ##########################
    imtg=""
    #define global variable to loop arround each image file.
    $party=""
    file_name_n.each { |a| puts a
    fname1 = "#{Base64.encode64(File.open(a, 'rb').read)}"

    part4=<<EOF
    Content-Type: image/png; name="#{a}"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="#{a}"

    #{fname1}
    --#{marker}
    EOF

    $party << part4

    imtg <<"<IMG SRC=\"#{a}\"  alt=\"#{a}\">"
    puts imtg
    }

    tabnam = File.open(table_name_n, 'rb').read
    puts tabnam

    ##########################
    # Build email body
    ##########################

    body = File.open(body, 'rb').read
    puts body
```

...
...
This actually puts the contents of the template as below. but wanted to replace the **"#{tabnam}"** and **"#{imtg}"** generated frob above.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Dashboards</title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',verdana;">
    <table width="100%" style="height: 100%;" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
    <!-- ============ HEADER SECTION ============== -->
    <td colspan="3" style="height: 100px;" bgcolor="#38424F" align="center"><h1><font size="3" color="white">#{report_name}</font></h1></td>
    </tr>



    <table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
    <td width="50%" align="right">
    #{tabnam}
    </td>
    <td width="50%" align="left">
    <IMG SRC="data_chart.png"  alt="data_chart.png">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- ============ MIDDLE COLUMN (CONTENT) ============== -->
    <td width="100%" colspan="3" valign="top" bgcolor="#FBFCFF" align="center">
    <!--#{tabnam}-->
    #{imtg}
    <br>
    <br>
```

**Update - Solution:**
Found the answer while i was playing with it. i just  need to use gsub.. simple solution.

```
body=body.gsub(/\#{tabnam}/, "#{tabnam}").gsub(/\#{imtg}/, "#{imtg}").gsub(/\#{report_name}/, "#{report_name}").gsub(/\#{rep_desc}/, "#{rep_desc}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: Solution:**
i found while playing with it. its simple gsub.

```
 body=body.gsub(/\#{tabnam}/, "#{tabnam}").gsub(/\#{imtg}/, "#{imtg}").gsub(/\#{report_name}/, "#{report_name}").gsub(/\#{rep_desc}/, "#{rep_desc}")
```